# Export RawQuerySet to excel with ExcelResponse. Error "ExcelResponse requires a sequence of sequences"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-views, export-to-excel

I try to download a view postgres to excel, it is possible with ExcelResponse ?

```
from excel_response import ExcelResponse
def vw_export_to_Excel(request):
    data = _Custumer.objects.raw('''select * from vw_customer''')
    return ExcelResponse(data, 'customer')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating the return value of the [`raw` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw) yields model instances, not a sequences.

Use `django.db.connection.cursor()` + `.execute` to get what you want.

```
from django.db import connection
from excel_response import ExcelResponse

def vw_export_to_Excel(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from vw_customer")
    return ExcelResponse(cursor.fetchall())
```

Or, use [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list):

```
from excel_response import ExcelResponse

def vw_export_to_Excel(request):
    data = list(_Custumer.objects.values_list())
    return ExcelResponse(data, 'customer')
```